How to convert a nested JSON to a Dataframe?
A response.json() returns a JSON in the following format:
{
    "workbooks": [
        {
            "name": "WORKBOOK_A",
            "embeddedDatasources": [
                {
                    "upstreamTables": [
                        {"name": "WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_A"}]},
                {
                    "upstreamTables": [
                        {"name": "WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_B"},
                        {"name": "WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_C"}]},
                {
                    "upstreamTables": []}]},
        {
            "name": "WORKBOOK_B",
            "embeddedDatasources": [
                {
                    "upstreamTables": [
                        {"name": "WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_A"},
                        {"name": "WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_B"}]},
                {
                    "upstreamTables": [
                        {"name": "WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_C"},
                        {"name": "WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_D"}]}]}]}

I am trying to convert it to a dataframe like this:



workbooks
upstreamTables




WORKBOOK_A
WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_A


WORKBOOK_A
WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_B


WORKBOOK_A
WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_C


WORKBOOK_B
WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_A


WORKBOOK_B
WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_B


WORKBOOK_B
WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_C


WORKBOOK_B
WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_D



"upstreamTables": [] should be ignored in this case.
Playing around with json_normalize
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data)

didn't play out so far and extracting the data as separate dataframes and rejoining them seems too convulsive.

Show us what you tried, please, so that we don't have to go over it again looking for a solution.

There are a bunch of related questions about converting nested JSON to dataframe; have you read any of them? Showing us what research you've done helps us rule things out when we're looking for a solution.

Also, it'd help to phrase the title as a question. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site after all. See [ask] for tips.

I checked out all related questions in the suggested questions sections pre publishing, in google AI, and from traditional searches. In retrospective, I should have posted my full json_normalization attempt and will keep your recommendations in mind regarding the title.

I assume you downvoted the other answers. If so, may I ask why?

Please [edit] the question to add those details.

I didn't downvote the answers and I'm not sure why someone would

Here's one approach:

Pass resp (i.e., response.json()) to pd.json_normalize with both record_path and meta. Add meta_prefix to avoid a ValueError: Conflicting metadata. Cf. this post. Otherwise we would end up with 2 name columns.
Use df.rename to rename the columns and re-order them.

import pandas as pd

# resp = {...}

df = (pd.json_normalize(resp['workbooks'], 
                        record_path=['embeddedDatasources', 'upstreamTables'], 
                        meta='name', 
                        meta_prefix='meta_'
                        )
      .rename(columns={'name': 'upstreamTables',
                       'meta_name': 'workbooks'})
      [['workbooks', 'upstreamTables']]
      )

Output:
    workbooks      upstreamTables
0  WORKBOOK_A  WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_A
1  WORKBOOK_A  WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_B
2  WORKBOOK_A  WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_C
3  WORKBOOK_B  WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_A
4  WORKBOOK_B  WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_B
5  WORKBOOK_B  WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_C
6  WORKBOOK_B  WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_D


Any particular reason for the downvote?

I didn't downvote it. Thanks so much, this resolved my issue, and I will make sure to read up more on json_normalize to wrap my head fully around it

to keep it compact I used list comprehensions, I hope it is readable.
import pandas as pd
    
responseData={}
for item in response['workbooks']:
    embbeddedDataList=item['embeddedDatasources']
    response_elements=[listElem['upstreamTables'] for listElem in embbeddedDataList if not listElem['upstreamTables']==[]]
    tabular_elements=[elem['name'] for elementList in response_elements for elem in elementList]
    responseData[item['name']]=tabular_elements
        
    
workbooks=[] ; upstreamTables=[]

for workbook in responseData:
    for streamEntry in responseData[workbook]:
        workbooks.append(workbook)
        upstreamTables.append(streamEntry)
        
tabularResponse=pd.DataFrame()
tabularResponse['workbooks']=workbooks
tabularResponse['upstreamTables']=upstreamTables


To convert the JSON response into the desired DataFrame, you can iterate through the JSON structure
import pandas as pd    

json_data = {
    "workbooks": [
        {
            "name": "WORKBOOK_A",
            "embeddedDatasources": [
                {"upstreamTables": [{"name": "WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_A"}]},
                {"upstreamTables": [{"name": "WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_B"}, {"name": "WORKBOOK_A_TABLE_C"}]},
                {"upstreamTables": []}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "WORKBOOK_B",
            "embeddedDatasources": [
                {"upstreamTables": [{"name": "WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_A"}, {"name": "WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_B"}]},
                {"upstreamTables": [{"name": "WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_C"}, {"name": "WORKBOOK_B_TABLE_D"}]}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
   
data = []    

for workbook in json_data['workbooks']:
    workbook_name = workbook['name']
    for datasource in workbook['embeddedDatasources']:
        for table in datasource['upstreamTables']:
            # Add workbook name and table name to the data list
            data.append({
                "workbooks": workbook_name,
                "upstreamTables": table['name']
            })    

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
print(df)

This would give the result in the desired table structure. But make sure to always pass the correct JSON or use any online tool like JSON Reader or any tool
